# how to keep track of currently logged user in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am a new user for zend framework. For my applications I need to keep track of currently logged in user, to do this I know I have to use  **zend_Auth** and **zend_Acl**, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well then the documentation would be the first place for you.

**Zend_Auth:** http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html

**Zend_Acl:** http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html

To get an easier access you could try this great tutorial series on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmtGClgImpo which covers every step from auth to acl.

---

To keep track of something you can use [**Zend_Registry**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.html), e.g.

```
Zend_Registry::set ( 'role', 'guests' );
```

and use the auth instance, e.g.

```
if(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()){
    Zend_Registry::set('role', Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()
                                                          ->read()->role);
}else{
    Zend_Registry::set('role', 'guests');
}
```

But this all is described very well in the tutorial.

Good Luck!

Comment: My situation is, I am having seperate controller called AuthenticationController to store the logged user details in session using Zend_Auth,Now i have to get the user info when every time user logged in and  access every page of the site. How can i do that in zend ?

Comment: @Dinesh you need to preDispatch every request, this is done using a plugin, here is a tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xHuGqQ7jEQ&feature=related